# ASP.NET Identity 2.0 Access control

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am currently developing an question & answer application (kind of a very basic stack overflow but for different area) using asp.net mvc 4 and asp.net identity 2.0 for external authentication. I want to show some edit/delete buttons to users for their own questions/answers and for the other people items there should not be any buttons and make sure that user's have access to edit/delete their own questions/answers and not others. I think the code should be written in the controller and page level along with some role based techniques. Can anyone please shed some light on this area. Thanks.

Comment: very simple You can check in your question table before edit or delete that the question is posted by this user or not.

Comment: @sagar43 thanks, please note that I have updated my question with more information.

Comment: When a user login you will get its username, ok?
Now when he send request to server for the question load, check each question with condition is this question is created by this user or not, set a bool variable for this and send that with the question on front end.
When you load your question on front end check that variable if its true then set button visible otherwise not.
If you did not get write your code i will edit that for you.

Comment: Hi @sagar43, Thanks for your detailed algorithm and also upvoted your comment. This is what i exactly thought initially (but not in a big way), but still thinking there should be some other standard way. Anyway am going to work on this initially, let us see if we get any other answers or how big guys like stack overflow implementations for the same thing.

Comment: Ok you can search If you need any help in this you are welcome.